# mouse events, whats wrong in my code

Tags: javascript, html

In the html part I don't want to include the events related code, events related code should be in inside the script tag

```html
<!doctype html>
  <head>
   <style>
      div{
           width:200px;
           background-color:grey;
         }
   </style>

   <body>
       <p>use the below area for events</p>
       <div> point here </div>  
       <a id="event_output"></a>

      <script>
         var output=document.getElementById("event_output").innerHTML;
         var div=document.getElementsByTagName("div");

         div[0].onmouseover=function(){output="mouse over"}
         div[0].onmouseout=function(){output="mouse out"}

      </script>                  
         

   </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just updating the `output` variable which is a string. Instead store the object reference and set its `innerHTML` property.

```html
<style>
  div {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
  }
</style>

<p>use the below area for events</p>
<div>point here</div>
<a id="event_output"></a>


<script>
  var output = document.getElementById("event_output");
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

  div[0].onmouseover = function() {
    output.innerHTML = "mouse over"
  }
  div[0].onmouseout = function() {
    output.innerHTML = "mouse out"
  }
</script>
```